# Unable to load shared library /home/kresh/.../node_sqlite3.node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

While trying to execute my nodejs application i get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to load shared library /home/kresh/tesi/webpcap/probe-manager/node_modules/sqlite3/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node
at Object..node (module.js:477:11)
at Module.load (module.js:353:32)
at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
at require (module.js:375:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kresh/tesi/webpcap/probe-manager/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:1:104)
at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
at Module.load (module.js:353:32)
at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
```

..even though i've installed the **sqlite3** module within **node_modules** directory. Could someone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

"Works better" if you upgrade nodejs and sqlite3. So i've uninstalled **nodejs** and **sqlite3** old versions and replaced them with the latest versions:

```
$ node --version
v0.10.8

$ sqlite3 --version
3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668
```

..and it worked.